# Simulating mutation in a population of cells. Numpy arr size manipulation efficiency

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on a project where we would like to figure out a way to estimate the mean generation a mutation first appears in a replicating population of cells through simulating the frequency in the population. I realize I could just track the first instance of it but this isn't going to be very helpful when dealing with populations of new cells and new mutations. I'd like to be able to do it through looking at the percentages of mutations in a grouping, given the mutation rate. For the simulation, we are starting with two cells of the wild type and simulating 30 generations (i.e.; all cells will replicate once in every generation). Meaning, the total number of cells at the end of the experiment will be 2^30 (i.e.; the number of cells double every generation 2-> 4, 4->8, 8->16 etc), and the generation of first appearance should be able to be predicted/estimated through the proportion of mutated cells in the final number of cells.

I figured the best way to do this was create one array containing an element for every cell that will be generated through the experiment, the starting position of which will be all zeros. The array will be updated after each generation dependent on the type of mutation and mutation rate, by changing the next slice of the array dependent on a random selection from a mutation array and mutation frequency array.

There are two types of mutation in my model and they will be designated with a +1 or a -1 with the frequency of the -1 being approximately 10X that of the +1 (0.0078, and 0.00079 respectively). I choose +1 and -1 so that I can also track multiple mutations of the same type in the cell line through the generations. For example if there is a -5 in the end product, I know that cell line has mutated in the -1 direction at least 5 times. Tracking a mutation back in the other direction I haven’t quite figured out how to detect in my model yet, but I will worry about that later.

As an example I will draw out what might happen if there was a mutation in the 2nd and 3rd generation and show what the 4th generation would look like in the array.

### My starting array for the population

[0,0,0,0,0,0,…,0] where # elements = 1,073,741,824

### Progenitor generation: Two wild type cells

[0, 0]

### 2nd generation: This generation splits to 4 cells with the second cell producing a -1 mutation

[0,0] -> [0,0,**0,-1**]   `- bold indicates the replicated cells`

Update the population array

[0,0,**0,-1**,...,0] where # elements = 1,073,741,824

### 3rd generation: This generation splits into 8 cells with the 4th cell still containing the -1 and now producing a copy of the -1, and the first cell producing another -1 mutation.

[0,0,0,-1] -> [0,0,0,-1,**-1,0,0,-1**]

Update the population array

[0,0,0,-1,**-1,0,0,-1**,...,0] where # elements = 1,073,741,824

### 4th generation: No mutations happen. This produces an exact copy of the previous generation

[0,0,0,-1,-1,0,0,-1] - > [0,0,0,-1,-1,0,0,-1,**0,0,0,-1,-1,0,0,-1**]

Update the population array

[0,0,0,-1,-1,0,0,-1,**0,0,0,-1,-1,0,0,-1**...,0] where # elements = 1,073,741,824

The trouble I am having is the length of time that the generation of the data is taking above 25 generations. I would like to be able to manipulate this simulation in multiple ways and do it many times but the time that the final generations are taking is prohibitive. Does anyone have any suggestions for a better or more efficient way to go about this simulation (besides doing less generations. 30 is a minimum we are looking for)?
My Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def mutation_model(total_splits, m_type1_freq, my_type2_freq):
    """Simulates mutation over n generations. You enter the number of generations, and the frequency of each mutation

     Parameters:
     ----------
     _total_splits:     integer
             The number of generations (ie splits). The total number of cells will be
             2^splits

     _m_type1_freq:    float
             The expected frequency of the occurrence of the first type of mutation.

     _my_type2_freq:      float
             The expected frequency of the occurrence of the second type of mutation.

    """
    # array for mutation type 1 (-1), wild type(0), and mutation type (1)
    mutation_types = np.array([-1, 0, 1])
    # frequency array to sample from
    mutation_freqs = np.array([m_type1_freq, 1-(m_type1_freq + my_type2_freq), my_type2_freq])
    # target number of cells
    cell_arr = np.zeros((2**total_splits, ), dtype=int)
    # multiplier
    exponent = 2

    # simulating generations
    for i in range(total_splits - 1):

        # make a copy of the first 2x part
        duplicate_arr = cell_arr[:exponent]

        # determine if the new copy will be rev, fwd, or a parent copy
        random_indices = np.random.choice(len(mutation_types), size=exponent, p=mutation_freqs)

        # get the new copy to update the next range of values in the array
        selection = mutation_types[random_indices]

        # update the next slice of the array
        cell_arr[exponent:(exponent * 2)] = np.add(duplicate_arr, selection)

        # increment exponent
        exponent *= 2

    dict_data = {'+2 mutation': np.count_nonzero(cell_arr == 2)/2**total_splits,
                 '+1 mutation': np.count_nonzero(cell_arr == 1)/2**total_splits,
                 'Wild type': np.count_nonzero(cell_arr == 0)/2**total_splits,
                 '-1 mutation': np.count_nonzero(cell_arr == -1)/2**total_splits,
                 '-2 mutation': np.count_nonzero(cell_arr == -2)/2**total_splits,
                 '-3 mutation': np.count_nonzero(cell_arr == -3)/2**total_splits,
                 '-4 mutation': np.count_nonzero(cell_arr == -4)/2**total_splits,
                 '-5 mutation': np.count_nonzero(cell_arr == -5)/2**total_splits}

    return dict_data


# pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
# pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

data = []


for i in range(100):
    print("Working on iteration: ", i + 1)
    mutation_dict = mutation_model(30, 0.078, 0.0076)
    data.append(mutation_dict)

df = pd.json_normalize(data)
# print(df)
df.to_csv('mutation.csv')
```

Comment: Im going to edit out the print function. I was only using that with small numbers of generations to make sure it was outputting correction.

Comment: Isn't a 32-bit integer a bit of an overkill for the datatype of `cell_arr`? On a quick look, it seems that you can only have -30..30 worse-case, so an 8-bit signed integer would be more than enough, reducing the size of the array to 25%. Given that you copy that data around multiple times, it might have some noticeable effect.

Comment: Anyway, it might be a good idea to grab a decent profiler (one that can deal with native code as well, since there's numpy involved (scalene seems to be interesting)) and find the expensive parts of your algorithm, so you know what to focus on.

Comment: If all you care about is the counts at the end, then you don't even need that huge array, you just need to keep track of the counts.

Comment: @Dan Mašek I hadn't thought of that. Thank you.

Comment: @jared, this is a thought. I have to think about whether or not I need the positional information afterwards though.  I appreciate the input, from both of you. If you guys can think of anything else, please let me know.

Comment: @jared, upon removal of updating the array, random selection is still taking a significant amount of time. Almost the same as without building the array. Not sure Im going to be able to get around the time I'm going to need to model this...

Comment: In the end, you're asking numpy to generate 1.1 billion numbers, so that takes time.

Comment: @jared that makes sense. I was just hoping someone smarter than me could figure out a way that it could work faster!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several performance issues in the code.

First of all, generating random numbers tends to be particularly expensive, especially if you want the generated numbers to be very-good random numbers. Numpy make a tread-off between the quality of the generated numbers and performance. On top of that, it can hardly make assumption on the probability provided nor the number of values. As a result, Numba uses a pretty generic code generating temporary values based on a lot of random bits that are mostly wasted.

Indeed, to produce an item from 3 possible values having the probability `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` you can generate random floating-point value `v` between 0 and 1 and then check if `v < p1` or `v < p1+p2` (assuming `p1+p2+p3=1`). The thing is generating `v` is not cheap, especially using 64-bit double-precision numbers.

In your case, you can generate (unsigned) integers and check if `v <= p1*(INT_MAX-1)` or `v <= (p1+p2)*(INT_MAX-1)`. Since 64-bit integers are quite slow to generate due to the number of random bits needed, you can use smaller integers. With 16-bits, the approximation should be relatively good with the provided parameters. With 8-bits, the probabilities `(0.078,0.9144,0.0076)` are truncated to `(0.07843,0.91373,0.00784)` which tends to be significantly different and might be an issue (it depends of what you actually need to do with this simulation).

Moreover, generating big temporary arrays is inherently slow (due to page faults and reading/writing in DRAM) though this is the common way to do compute things in Numpy. Data need to be generated and computed on the fly as much as possible to avoid slow DRAM access and page faults. Using small data-types also helps to reduce the memory usage (smaller arrays are faster to read and write in memory). While this is sometime possible in Numpy by operating on chunks, this is cumbersome to do (and still not very efficient either). One solution is to use compiler-based tools like Cython or Numba. They can also be used to parallelize easily your code efficiently in this case.

Besides, note that `mutation_types[random_indices]` is particularly expensive while here we can just write `random_indices - 1`.

---

### Implementation

Here is an example of Numba code generating the indices more efficiently:

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('(int64, float64, float64, float64)', parallel=True)
def gen_random_mutations(size, p1, p2, p3):
    assert(np.isclose(p1+p2+p3, 1.0))
    res = np.empty(size, dtype=np.int8)
    int_max = 1_000_000_000
    t1 = np.int32(np.round(p1 * (int_max-1)))
    t2 = np.int32(np.round((p1+p2) * (int_max-1)))
    for i in nb.prange(size):
        v = np.random.randint(0, int_max) # 32-bit on Windows machines
        res[i] = (v > t1) + (v > t2) - 1
    return res

# Usage: 
# selection = gen_random_mutations(exponent, 0.07843, 0.91373, 0.00784)
```

---

### Results and notes

This is about **25 times faster** than both calling `np.random.choice` and doing `mutation_types[random_indices]` on my 6-core i5-9600KF CPU.

The above code use the default pseudo-random number generator (PRNG). It is not optimal here since it generates 32-bit integers in a specific range while we can directly produce 16-bit integers without performing any scaling. Besides, one can make it more SIMD-friendly. You can find an [example of fast custom PRNG in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74660595/further-optimizing-the-ising-model/74670134#74670134).

Note that is might be faster to convert the line using `np.add` in Numba too, at least to avoid a temporary array followed by a copy (not to mention it can certainly be parallelized too).

Comment: This. This is fantastic. Thank you. I know very little of those libraries but now I have a very good reason to learn them! Thank you. Thank you. Thank you.